# How to distinguish "complex network" and "social network"?

Tags: philosophy-of-social-sciences

From reading a paper of [Murase, 2019](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-40990-z), I saw a sentence

> The system that emerges due to inter-personal tie formation,
> constitutes a social network, which is one of the paradigmatic
> examples of complex networks

From my understanding, this sentence means that complex networks contain social network (inter-personal tie information). But I do not understand what is the difference between "complex network "and "social network".

I saw the definition of [complex network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_network) here but I get lost that I do not full understand. Would you please help me to clarify it?
I personally think the difference would be that social network is about "person" and "complex network is "non-human things", is it a correct thought?

Comment: A network is social when it represents social ties, biological when it represents some system in a living organism, technological when it represents some technological processes or devices, and so on. On the other hand, complexity of a network is determined by the structure of connections in it, and not by what it represents. "Complex" is a synonym of "complicated". This property applies to any network whatsoever, human, non-human or representing nothing at all, just a mathematical abstraction.

Comment: @Conifold, so it means that, when talking to human being, "complex network"= "social network"?

Comment: No, it means the opposite, complexity has nothing to do with humans or socialness. Social network can be simple, with just two people, for example, and complex network may have no people at all, like an electric circuit. Some social networks just happen to be complex.

Comment: @Conifold , I got it, thanks a heap

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because question of general definition.